# Sequelize: How to get most recent unique records?

Tags: sequelize.js

I've table containing messages between users.

`{ message, senderId, receiverId, createdAt, updatedAt, id }`

For given User, I want to return a list of people that user has ever talked to and sorted by date of last message from either one whichever is latest.

`Person D, Person A, Person C, Person Z, ....`

User column has these: `{ name, createdAt, updatedAt, id }`

Comment: You need to include more info - model definitions, all the columns (date?), etc

Comment: added column names

Answer (score 0):

Query for all Messages and use the `Op.or` query filter to find records where your user id matches either the send sender or receiver, then order by the `createdAt` in descending order. Use `raw` to avoid creating `Instance` objects, then loop over the results and collect the user IDs by reducing the `messages` array.

```js
const userId = ???;
const messages = await Message.findAll({
  attributes: ['senderId', 'receiverId', 'createdAt'],
  where: {
    [Op.or]: {
      senderId: userId,
      receiverId: userId,
    },
  },
  order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
  raw: true, // get raw since we don't need to bother creating Instances
});

// use an object to collect unique IDs
const userIds = {};
// reduce messages to collect userIds and createdAt
const userIds = messages.reduce((userIds, message) => {
  // check the senderId and recieverId
  ['senderId', 'recieverId'].forEach((column) => {
    // if it's not our userId and not already in the list, add it
    if (message[column] !== userId && !userIds[message[column]]) {
      // you could check things about message.createdAt here, or use JSON for more info
      userIds[message[column]] = message.createdAt;
    }
  });
  // return the accumulator
  return userIds;
}, {});

console.log('User IDs', userIds);
```

Comment: this gives me all messages, which is close but i want list of all user ids i've gotten a message or messaged to

Comment: im still concerned as this would pull all messages across from every user this person has messaged ever.