# Select only unique / distinct rows (based on column) from an included model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a number of tables that are related. It can be condensed down to: `Product`, `Offer`

Each `Product` has a lot of `Offers` from many stores. Each `Offer` is an offer at the given time, so only the most recent offer is always the current one.

---

***I want to list all `Products` with their most recent (newest) `Offer` from each `Store`.***

This is my base query that is working to give me **all** `Products` with **all** their respective `Offer`s.

```
const products = await Product.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Offer,
        as: 'offers',
        order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    }]
});
```

**What I want to get from this, however, is all `Products` and only the newest / most recent `Offer` of each store as identified by `Offer.store_id`.**

---

Research:

So far I learned that distinct is definitely the wrong approach, as that matches whole lines and that I need to use GROUP BY (sequelize `group`). Sadly all of my attempts proved fruitless.

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160064/mysql-using-distinct-for-only-one-column) Person wants pretty much what I want to have - I just need it on my included (/joined) Model and working in sequelize.
- I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557465/sequelize-how-to-get-most-recent-unique-records) person is looking for the same solution, but the proposed one is terrible and inefficient and does not utilize sequelize to achieve the result.
- I have tried various proposed solutions [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130692/postgres-sequelize-group-isnt-working-when-referencing-the-include-table-colu)], [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130692/postgres-sequelize-group-isnt-working-when-referencing-the-include-table-colu)], [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568552/group-by-with-sequelize)] (and many more) using `group`, none of which helped me get a result and all resulted in MYSQL exceptions.

I can't imagine that this can be so hard to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a brain-melting 6 hour session with ChatGPT and trying endless approaches I managed to find a working Solution. Actually I found both a working SQL Query and a completely different, but working, Sequelize model query using a literal subquery.

This is the Sequelize query:

```
const products = await Product.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Offer,
    where: {
      createdAt: {
        [Op.eq]: Sequelize.literal(
          '(SELECT MAX(createdAt) FROM offers o2 WHERE offers.product_id = o2.product_id AND offers.store_id = o2.store_id)'
        ),
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

`store_id` is the column on `Offer` that identifies the Store of which only the latest entry should be returned.

Its surprisingly short of a query, which I kind of expected but was surprised to see almost no coverage on the use-case.